# TypeScript interface implementation with extra parameter object member does not yield expected compilation error

Tags: typescript

Consider the following types:

```js
type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

interface UsersRepository {
  getUser(query: { id: string }): User;
}

class Repo implements UsersRepository {
  getUser({ id, name }: { id: string; name: string }) {
    return { id, name: name.toUpperCase() };
  }
}

const illustrateProblem = () => {
  const repo: UsersRepository = new Repo();

  console.log(repo.getUser({ id: "foo" }));
};

illustrateProblem();
```

Note that the implementation method requires *two* properties on the input object; `id` and `name`, while the interface only requires `id`.

This yields no compilation errors!

However, at runtime, this code will fail because the call to `repo.getUser` does not provide a `name` on its argument, so it will be `undefined` and `name.toUpperCase()` will throw an error. In other words, `name` is `undefined` at runtime, even though the TypeScript compiler thinks it can never be so.

Why does TypeScript allow this?

---

Clarification: I know that this implementation invalidates the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and that's the point: I would have expected TypeScript to yell at me for doing that, by giving an error on the declaration of the implementation of `getUser` that the method cannot implement the interface, because it requires fields on its argument that are not defined in the signature on the interface.

Comment: The problem isn't TypeScript, it's that Repo breaks the LSP. If you typed repo as Repo rather than UsersRepository, TS could tell you getUser needs more information.

Comment: FYI  `getUser({ id: string }): User;` is an error, maybe you mean `getUser(arg: {id: string}): User;`

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks, updated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, but this is a contrived example. In a real application, the repo might come as a method parameter or via some other indirection. I would not have expected an error at the call site, but rather at the implementation, that _tells me_ this violates LSP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to [method parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) in TypeScirpt.  This is one of the places where the type system is unsound, allowing you to do unsafe things.  Apparently there's plenty of real-world code where subclasses expect [methods to accept *more specific* arguments instead of more general arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_parameter_type).  TypeScript supports this by intentionally accepting either wider (safe) or narrower (unsafe) arguments, and you unfortunately just tripped over it.

Luckily, since TypeScript 2.6 there has been a [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types) compiler flag that disables function argument bivariance (and only allows contravariance).  Unluckily, even with this flag turned on, it only applies to standalone functions and not class methods.  *Luckily*, with an interface there is actually a (not well-documented) way to distinguish a method signature from a function-valued property signature:

```
interface Foo<A, R> {
   methodSignature(arg: A): R;
   functionSignature: (arg: A) => R;
}
```

Both `methodSignature` and `functionSignature` refer to function-like things that hang off of a `Foo`, and in practice you can implement either one with a prototype-based method or with an instance-valued function property.  And, luckily, the function-property signature will obey `--strictFunctionTypes`.  Therefore I'd change `UsersRepository`'s definition to this:

```
interface UsersRepository {
  getUser: (a: { id: string }) => User;
}
```

and suddenly you'll see the error you were expecting:

```
class Repo implements UsersRepository {
  getUser({ id, name }: { id: string; name: string }) {
    // error!  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ id: string; }'
    // but required in type '{ id: string; name: string; }'.
    return { id, name: name.toUpperCase() };
  }
}
```

And therefore you can fix it:

```
class FixedRepo implements UsersRepository {
  getUser({ id, name }: { id: string; name?: unknown }) {
    return {
      id,
      name: (typeof name === "string" ? name : "nobody").toUpperCase()
    };
  }
}

const illustrateProblem = () => {
  const repo: UsersRepository = new FixedRepo();
  console.log(repo.getUser({ id: "foo" }));
};

illustrateProblem(); // { id: "foo", name: "NOBODY" }
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4CCAaZAJQD5kBvAKGWQFsIwALdAEwGVgBzEOMAVyggAKOFA4AuZDgCUEwgG4qyGLxAIwwdCHZce-CBOGiJ05AF5S8igF8KFMAE8ADigCqAZ2hnyi4MwluwKFAOBWpuOn9A4IUrBQpQSFhEVw8oN0IIR3Q3YDB0KHtvag56d2gDOAkyZF9IoJAOZCspM1IyqBjbBAAbODc3Ikz0GppHbog6cAH29KGcvIKi5BKwdsFq3wJwlCsqmr9kAPqQ5G264KaWympqAHpb5GgofIBCagAFZ+coB2QAcm2fxqAxowH6F1AyAczn+GwOR2iTT+ijuDwARrwwMgBABHXjAATMGogKFOFB-OHnBpyU5wCKHKLUpEAOhR2Po-BJcK2dP0tLozLyLkc3wAwn0hC1YoobDYKD0+gNUMAAB4QZgZLIjMYTCBTZAzTXZXL5QrXZalVLrfY8uhNPa1BnHGnbAD8EhUAGsQOgAO4k5pLagCPhQLls6ibCP8vmCaEQdAwGNmUymZAAIgRDXTyFdyYk6Z9aJY9nTUkF6GFYolgikbOl1FlXU0ARq3W6vCOPAgn3QaPGNC8tdaSwQLaxAiyEkNcxNizTIAgvrQqvVRtroWQY5AbnQ42Z3XQHEEk-QzJWa0pGZgmBzzSkMTiwHbncC3d7-YmG+Q93I+wLN7oOmtp8umAByADyABCEEACIAJp3hQQA)